# nested division tags different background

Tags: html, css, background

I can't get the second divsion tag's background image to show on top of the first.  I assumed nesting these would work but neither the 2nd division tag or img i put it shows up.

Here is my code.  It is supposed to put a white/gray image repeating down the middle with the image inside.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"       
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-   
flowers/Background-2013.gif') ;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-color:black; overflow:none;}


.bgimg-paisley {
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-  
flowers/black-paisley-background.jpg');
    height:87%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

.bgimgborder {
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-  
flowers/runner-for-paisley-test.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width:720px;
    height:87%;
}

-->
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="bgimg-paisley"   
style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:0px;width:100%;>
     <div class="bgimgborder" style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:200px;>
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-
flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg"  width="700px">
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing closing quotes for style attributes:

In your snippet:

```
style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:0px;width:100%;
style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:200px;
```

Should be:

```
style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:0px;width:100%;"
style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:200px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

When overlapping html elements its useful to note the `z-index` css property of your tags in question.  It essentially tells the browser which elements should be viewed on top of others.  The higher the `z-index` the higher the precedence.  I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcyttcgz/1/) with your code and set the `img` tags `z-index` to 100 and it showed right up.

Comment: I also closed the quotes for two of your inline style tags btw.